# How can I limit connections to my web application per minute?

Tags: php, proxy, nginx, limiting

I have tried to use nginx (http://nginx.org/) to limit the amount of requests per minute. For example my settings have been:

```
server{
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=pw:5m rate=20r/m; 
}
location{
limit_req zone=pw nodelay;
}
```

What I have found with Nginx is that even if I try 1 request per minute, I am allowed back in many times within that minute. Of course fast refreshing of a page will give me the limit page message which is a "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" return code.

I want to know what kind of settings can be applied to limit a request exactly to 20 requests a minute. I am not looking for flood protection only because Nginx provides this where if a page is constatnly refreshed for example it limits the user and lets them back in after some time with some delay (unless you apply a nodelay setting).

If there is an alternative to Nginx other than HAProxy (because its quite slow). Also the setup I have on Nginx is acting as a reverse proxy to the real site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right there's 2 things:

1. the limit_conn directive in combination with a limit_conn_zone lets you limit the number of (simultaneous) connnections from an ip (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html#limit_conn)
2. the limit_req directive in combination with a limit_req_zone lets you limit the number of request from a given ip per timeunit (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req)

note:

- you need to do the limit_conn_zone/limit_req_zone in the http block not the serverblock
- you then refer to the zone name you set up in the http block from within the server/location block with the etup zone with the limit_con/limit_req settings (as approriate)

since you stated below you're looking to limit requests you need the limit_req directives. Specically to get a max 5 requests per minute, try adding the following:

```
http {
  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=example:10m rate=5r/m;
}

server {
   limit_req zone=example burst=0 nodelay;
}
```

note: obviously add those to your existing http/server blocks

Comment: Had a look and tried this out, I don't think will limit a request in the way I want. It will limit IP connections but what I am looking for is a limiting of requests from an IP. So the IP of 127.0.0.1 called my webpage at location X and after 5 refreshed pages for the minute they can't see anything until that minute is over.

Comment: Your right about where the lines should be placed and this is fine within my configuration. Also writing burst=0 fails the config test because burst has to have a value greater than 0. When I implement the rate of 5 per minute without burst. I expect 5 refreshes to disconnect me for a minute if anythign is hit after that. Instead I get odd behavior, one refresh will be fine but then next one won't be, a slight wait and its working again. In the minute I can definitely get more than 5 requests.

Comment: @namsu55: Nginx doesn't work that way, you can only limit per second, possibly with temporary bursts. See https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/251331cd59f780fca94bef334f58a6e311e4ad32/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.c#L797

Comment: A more user-friendly guide than the nginx module documentation can be found at: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/